# How to install Requests for PHP in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, installation, httprequest, ubuntu-14.04

How to install Requests for PHP (http://requests.ryanmccue.info/) on Ubuntu 14.04?

I have downloaded package with command:

```
$ wget https://github.com/rmccue/Requests/tarball/master -O - | tar xzv
```

In Phyton next step would be:

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

What command would I use for PHP?

Comment: The **Installation** chapter on the very page you link to didn't help...?!

Comment: I thought to integrate it with PHP, not to call it from script. Is it possible? From script I would just use it now as it is with: require_once '/path/to/Requests/library/Requests.php';?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/462673/installing-php-5-3-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: The instructions to install are *on the exact page* you linked to in your first sentence. http://requests.ryanmccue.info/#installation

Comment: What's your definition of "integrate with PHP"?

Answer (score 0):

If you install via [composer](https://getcomposer.org/), which I recommend you do, you can then include it just by including the 'autoload.php' that composer generates for you. Usually from your project root

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php'
```

but that will depend on the structure of your project. Then you're freely able to use

```
Requests::get($args); // or, of course, any of the other functions
```

from within your project.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's a compiled PHP extension, there is no installation step for PHP libraries. You download the files, you put them in a folder, you `require` the file you just downloaded. Typically you make those dependencies part of your PHP project instead of installing them "globally". [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) was created to simplify that process and help you manage dependencies. If you don't use it, it's up to you where to put those files and where to `require` them from.